# Dataprep - Append data to BigQuery table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

I'm using GCP's dataprep to join several csv files with the same column structure, treat some data and then write to a BigQuery database.

I have to record this data in  BigQuery. Can I include this data from the dataprep and append them in a BigQuery table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can include your data from DataPrep and append them in a BigQuery table.

Before running the job, in the "Run Job on DataFlow" section:

1. Click on the action, since you are using BigQuery for the output, should look like "Create-BigQuery"
2. In the next windows choose you output table
3. In the left panel select "Append to this table every run"
4. Click on update

Now, when you run the Job, this will append your data.

The following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Run-Job-Page_57344897#publishing-actions) can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is possibility to truncate data or append data to BigQuery table. In the output step DataPrep step in BigQuery table selection you can set that will be appended to table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My difficultly is in "Connect your data" step. I have plenty of tables with the prefix `events_` and I want them all. My intuition is to parameterize doing that `events_*`, but I do not have this option in bigquery table ingestion.

[image: Step that I want to parametrize]