# How can I parameterize a BigQuery table in Dataprep?

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I'm used to use Dataprep to recipe json and csv files from Cloud Storage, but today I tried to ingest a table from BigQuery and could not parametrize.

Is it possible to do that?

Here are some screenshots to illustrate my question:

[The prefix that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oge9i.jpg)

[The standard does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9qic.png)

[From Cloud Storage works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hmxz.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dataprep - Append data to BigQuery table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63381560/dataprep-append-data-to-bigquery-table)

Answer (score 0):

In order to ingest a table from BigQuery, you can directly [create a Dataset with SQL](https://docs.trifacta.com/display/DP/Create+Dataset+with+SQL). I am not sure on what you would like to achieve with the 'Search' input, but it does not accept regular expressions. So, the '*' would not be needed, and just writing 'event_', the interface will filter the matching entries.